# Does this stackoverflow forum answer questions related to IELTS?

Tags: discussion

I am a programmer but seeking emigration in an English speaking country, which requires IELTS band of 7 in each module.Can I use this forum for IELTS? If not please suggest me other forum similar to stackoverflow.

Comment: Actually that wouldn't be a bad idea to propose, a site for candidates wanting to take English exams such as: [CAE](http://www.cambridgeenglish.org/exams/advanced/), [Trinity ESOL](http://www.trinitycollege.com/site/?id=263), IELTS, [GRE](http://www.ets.org/gre), and [TOEFL](http://www.ets.org/toefl) (and any others I may have missed out on)

Comment: In re: *can I use this site for IELTS*, it's not clear what the implications of that would be. So long as your questions are clear, well-researched, and on topic, you are welcome to ask them here. I see your *purpose* in asking them (in this case, to pass a test) as rather orthogonal to those goals. However, two warnings: it's *harder* to ask a good question than most people think, and StackExchange does not, by design, offer the kind of back-and-forth discussion you might hope for as you study a topic.

Comment: In re: *if not here, then where; if not StackExchange then what other sites?*: this site (EL&U) has a large population of native speakers of English, who have never had to study for or take an English proficiency test. In other words, many of us have *no idea* what kinds of resources are out there for students of the language, and can't make any recommendations (we can point you to our favorite dictionaries, or corpora, etc, of course, but I don't think that's what you're looking for). On the other hand, we *do* have a sister site: [ELL.se].

Comment: @DanBron sitting and passing English exams is not the same as learning a language for communicative purposes, the higher the level the more the candidate has to study the grammar, the lexis, and practise his or her listening. I was thinking along the lines of proposing a new site in the  SE 51 thingy http://area51.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Mari-LouA I have never used Area51, but my impression is the mods there have itchy trigger fingers when it comes to closing proposals as "too much overlap w/ existing sites". We'll have to come up with a strong case for why these questions are outside the charter of ELL (which has *learning* right in the name).

Comment: For English exams at an academic level, a potential candidate is better off here, but I know at least two users who would strongly disagree with me.

Comment: I often encourage obvious non-native speakers to check out ELL, because I think there's an art and a science to *explaining* the technicalities of English to non-native speakers, beyond the details of those technicalities themselves. A big part of that is being familiar with what common things trip up learners coming from specific backgrounds (I'm sure you could write a treatise on common errors made by Italians learning English!). But if someone asks a difficult or sophisticated question or specifically requests a deep explanation, why, I love those kinds of questions here.

Comment: s/stackoverflow/Stack Exchange

Answer (score 5):

If the questions related to IELTS are about how to pass the exam, then the 
 plain answer is ‘no’. This site does not cater for candidates wishing to *prepare* for any one of the dozen English language exams that are currently available.

However, nowhere on the help centre is this clearly stated

> But please, don’t ask any questions about [the following topics](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). They are out of scope for this site.
>
> - Proofreading ("Is this right?", "Are there any mistakes?"), unless the source of concern is clearly specified
> - Writing advice (see Writers.SE instead) or critique requests
> - **"How to improve my English?"** (this is not constructive anyway)
> - Translation and non-English languages — please see the translation tag info for details
> - Naming, including naming programming variables/classes
> - Criticism, discussion, and analysis of English literature
> - Jokes that do not rely on the English language

Questions asking about exam preparation is covered by “How to improve my English”, but perhaps that could also include a side comment, similar to;

- e.g. asking for advice about English language exams.